# How to sort this list by distance? Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, sorting

I have this list and I want to sort it by distance which is this 'lat' and 'lng' its so difficult to do it since I add this lazy loader to my list, here is my full code:

```
    class ListPage  extends StatefulWidget {
      late final AppController appController;
      ListPage(appController){
        this.appController = appController;
      }
    
      @override
      _ListPageState createState() => _ListPageState();
    }
    
    class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {
      late double unitHeightValue;
      final myController = TextEditingController();
      bool firstTime = false;
      String evseSearchField = "";
      Evse evse = new Evse(evseID: 0, friendlyName: "", street: "", streetNumber: "", region: "", lat: 0.0, lng: 0.0, connectorList: [], cpSerial: "", img: "");
      late List<EvsePanel> evsePanels = [new EvsePanel(evse, widget.appController, true)];
      late TextField searchTextField = TextField(
        controller: myController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: 'Search',
          fillColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      );
    
      final controller = ScrollController();
      List<String> items = [];
      bool hasMore = true;
      int page = 1;
      bool isLoading = false;
    
      @override
      void initState(){
        super.initState();
    
        fetch();
    
        controller.addListener(() {
          if (controller.position.maxScrollExtent == controller.offset) {
            fetch();
          }
        });
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        myController.dispose();
        controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      void refreshEvsePanels() async{
        const refreshSeconds = const Duration(seconds: 5);
        Timer.periodic(refreshSeconds, (Timer t) {
          if(!mounted) {
            t.cancel();
            return;
          }
          showEvsePanels();
        });
      }
      void showEvsePanels() async{
widget.appController.evseList.sort((a, b){
      int nameComp = a.sort_availability.compareTo(b.sort_availability);
      if (nameComp == stationAvailability.available.index) {
        return a.distance.compareTo(b.distance); // '-' for descending
      }
      return nameComp;
});

        setState(() {
          if (evseSearchField.isEmpty){
            int i = 0;
            if (tempEvses.length != 0){
              evsePanels.clear();
              while (i < tempEvses.length){
                evsePanels.add(new EvsePanel(tempEvses[i], widget.appController, false));
                i++;
              }
            }
          }
          else{
            int i = 0;
            if (tempEvses.length != 0){
              evsePanels.clear();
              while (i < tempEvses.length){
                if (containsIgnoreCase(tempEvses[i].friendlyName, evseSearchField))
                  evsePanels.add(new EvsePanel(
                      tempEvses[i], widget.appController, false));
                i++;
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
      List<Evse> tempEvses = [];
    
      Future fetch() async {
        if (isLoading) return;
        isLoading = true;
    
        const limit = 10;
        final url = Uri.parse('https://everywhere-dev.iccs.gr:18083/evse/getEvsesPaged?page=$page&pageLimit=$limit');
        final response = await http.get(url);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          final List newItems = json.decode(response.body)["results"];
    
          setState(() {
            page++;
            isLoading = false;
    
            if (newItems.length <limit) {
              hasMore = false;
            }
            tempEvses.addAll(newItems.map<Evse>((items) {
              final evseID = items['evseID'];
              final friendlyName = items['friendlyName'];
              final street = items['street'];
              final streetNumber = items['streetNumber'];
              final region = items['region'];
              final lat = items['lat'] ?? 0.0;
              final lng = items['lng'] ?? 0.0;
              final connectorList = items['connectorList'];
              final cpSerial = items['cpSerial'];
              final img = items['img'];
    
    
              return new Evse(evseID: evseID, friendlyName: friendlyName, street: street, streetNumber: streetNumber, region: region, lat: lat, lng: lng, connectorList: [connectorList], cpSerial: cpSerial, img: img);
    
    
            }).toList());
            for(int i=0 ; i<tempEvses.length; i++  ){
              this.tempEvses[i].calculateDistance(widget.appController.currentLocation);
            //  this.tempEvses[i].calculateAvailability();
              this.tempEvses[i].isEvseFavorite(widget.appController.favoritesList);
              this.tempEvses[i].storePlugCounters();
            }
            showEvsePanels();
          });
        }
      }
    
      Future refresh() async{
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
          hasMore =true;
          page = 0;
          tempEvses.clear();
        });
        fetch();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        if(!firstTime){
          this.unitHeightValue = widget.appController.queryData.size.height * 0.001;
          showEvsePanels();
          //refreshEvsePanels();
          firstTime = true;
        }
    
        return  SizedBox(
            height: widget.appController.queryData.size.height,
            width : widget.appController.queryData.size.width,
    
            child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: widget.appController.queryData.size.height/12,
                    width: widget.appController.queryData.size.width * (9/10),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: widget.appController.themeController.appWhiteLightColor,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: widget.appController.themeController.appGreyLightColor.withOpacity(0.6),
                            spreadRadius: 1,
                            blurRadius: 1,
                            offset: Offset(0, 2), // changes position of shadow
                          ),
                        ],
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                    ),
                    child:Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children:[
                          Container(
                            width: widget.appController.queryData.size.width * (7/10),
                            child: searchTextField,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: IconButton(
                              color: widget.appController.themeController.appBlackDeepColor,
                              tooltip: 'Search',
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                              iconSize: 32 * this.unitHeightValue,
                              onPressed: () {
                                this.evseSearchField = myController.text;
                                showEvsePanels();
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: RefreshIndicator(
                        onRefresh: refresh,
                        child: ListView.separated(
                            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
                            controller: controller,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            itemCount: evsePanels.length + 1,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              if (index < evsePanels.length) {
                                return evsePanels[index];
                              } else {
                                return  Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: hasMore
                                        ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                                        : const Text('No more data to load'),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                            }
                        ),
                      )
                  )
                ]
            )
        );
      }
      bool containsIgnoreCase(String str1, String str2) {
        return str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase());
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that demonstrates the problem?  Or at least describe your problem more fully?  Even if you have a lazily loaded list, why can't you sort it after your list has finished loading?  Or if your list gets items added to it one-by-one, you could use [`insertionSort`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/insertionSort.html) with the added item.

Answer (score 0):

You can look this link to learn more thing about sort method.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/sort.html

Comment: as you can see i use this method but it doesnt work since i add lazy loader function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).